# Smoke detector position vs air register

Tags: smoke-detectors

Are there regulations about positioning a smoke detector in the vicinity of an air register? I would like to position it within 3 ft aerial distance but I'm concerned the air flow might be blowing smoke away from the detector therefore causing a false negative, which is like not having a detector.

Answer (score 3):

### You are correct to be concerned!

NFPA 72 (my cite is from the 2010 edition, but this rule hasn't changed in the last decade I reckon) 29.8.3.4 point 6 covers your situation:

> (6) Smoke alarms and smoke detectors shall not be installed
> within a 36 in. (910 mm) horizontal path from the supply registers of a forced air heating or cooling system and
> shall be installed outside of the direct airflow from those
> registers.

So, either the smoke detector or the air register has to move, lest airflow from the register create what you describe with a false-negative result due to smoke being blown away from the detector.

Comment: Do they make “deflectors” that could be mounted on the supply register? (I’ve seen them mounted on floor registers.)

Comment: @LeeSam -- I have no idea unfortunately